# Kendo Grid InCell Editing => saveEvent(e) => e.values

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm using a Grid from Kendo UI to display a bunch of data and now I want to add InCell editing.

Since JavaScript isn't my strongest point, I can't see a solution to my following problem:

The Grid is defined as:

```
.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Selectable(e => e.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Cell))
.Events(events => events.Save("subfileSaved")
```

With the batch mode of the datasource set to false.

Now in my `subfileSaved(e)` function, I get the changed values in `e.values`. According to Firebug, the value of `e.values` is `Object { Fields[2].Content="11CLS1511"}`.

**Question:** How can I best extract both the `2` from the `Fields[2].Content` as well as getting the `11CLS1511`?

**Edit:** `e.values.Fields[2].Content` doesn't work, see [image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by extract both the `2` from `Fields[2].Content`?. I suspect `Fields` is an array here where `2` is the index and `Content` is the property of the object in that index.

Comment: @NaveenBhat I tried `var tmp = e.values.Fields[2].Content`, but then I get a `TypeError: e.values.Fields is undefined`. (And I also don't know beforehand, if my function will get a 2, 5 or whatever number below 20). Maybe it is just a simple error on my side, which will result in much forehead slapping ;-)

Comment: In `firebug` or any other console, if you are able to see `Object { Fields[2].Content="11CLS1511"}` for `e.values`, then you wouldn't be getting this error. For safer side you can write like this - `var tmp = e.values.Fields ? e.values.Fields[2] ? e.values.Fields[2].Content : null : null`

Comment: @NaveenBhat So what am I doing wrong? See the screeenshot at [link](http://i.imgur.com/al4Ce9y.png).

Comment: It looks strange to me. Please update your question with this screenshot.

Comment: you can get the "11CLS1511" value like this, e.values["Fields[2].Content"]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "Fields" is a collection you can access or is it rather the enumeration of your ViewModel by Firebug?

For example, what is the Model that you grid is bound to?

If I have a grid with a model like so;

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<AddressListViewModel>().Name("AddressList")
          .Columns(c2 =>
                                                   {
         c2.Bound(w => w.AddressTypeId).Title("Address Type").ClientTemplate("<#= AddressTypeDisplay #>");
          c2.Bound(w => w.AddressDisplay).Title("Common Name");
```

..miss a few

```
          .Events(events => events.Save("subfileSaved"))
```

Then on Save I can inspect all the values such as this;

```
function subfileSaved(e) {
    var someValue = e.Model.AddressDisplay;

    debugger;

}
```

Kendo does all the hard work for you and gives you a nice named instance to read of the model and the Fields. I am just wondering if you need to access the Model and Properties explicitly but without your full grid code hard to say exactly.